# font-size: calc only working on certain pages/browsers, even with prefixes

Tags: css, file, mobile, calc

I'm working on a major website for a company which I will not disclose, for privacy reasons. The desktop version of the site works completely fine and everything is where it is supposed to be regarding markup, functionality, presentation and backwards-compatibility. Going onto mobile, for some reason, has messed up the font-size calc() feature of CSS so that almost every page seems to have the default unchanging font sizes that don't scale. It seems to only be the landing page/index.html that is appropriately "linked" to the stylesheet that is shared between all of the pages. I've tried changing around the margins, padding, etc. I've also tried using different browsers (Safari, Firefox Android, Google Chrome Android, etc), using prefixes and changing file locations. I made absolutely sure that the file linking was exactly the same across all 15 pages on the site. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's the CSS code made for mobile devices from that file. Is is compatibility issues? Default styles from mobile browsers? I believe the origin of the issue comes from this area, but I can't be sure. I will post more code if deemed necessary by those willing to help. I appreciate anyone who is able to do so.

Thanks,

Justin

Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  h1 {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(1rem + 4vw);
    font-size: calc(1rem + 4vw);
  }
  h2 {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(1rem + 3vw);
    font-size: calc(1rem + 3vw);
  }
  h3 {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(1rem + 2.5vw);
    font-size: calc(1rem + 2.5vw);
  }
  header {
    align-items: center;
  }
  input {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(0.3rem + 1vw);
    font-size: calc(0.3rem + 1vw);
  }
  header ul li a {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(0.5rem + 1.1vw);
    font-size: calc(0.5rem + 1.1vw);
  }
    a,
  address,
  footer,
  label,
  li,
  p,
  select,
  td {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(0.6rem + 1.15vw);
    font-size: calc(0.6rem + 1.15vw);
  }
  .arrow {
    animation: arrowMove 200ms ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
  }
  .arrowTwo {
    animation: arrowMoveTwo 200ms ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards;
  }
  #Layer_1_1_ {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(0.8rem + 0.75vw);
    width: calc(0.8rem + 0.75vw);
  }
  #arrow {
        font-size: -webkit-calc(2.25rem + 1.5vw);
    width: calc(2.25rem + 1.5vw);
  }
  #login {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  #xoutbtn {
    width: 40px;
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  #login-form *:not(img) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header ul li {
    display: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3 {
    margin: 0.5em auto;
  }
  @keyframes arrowMove {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes arrowMoveTwo {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as long as it is working for one page, then you have to check other pages for what blocking the style file.. i dun think it's related to the css code, try to find out the differences between your working page and the others !

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Do the styles show up at all? Are they being overridden by some other styles?